# Accessing home server from the Internet

Tags: apache-http-server, port-forwarding, isp

I'm having a bit of difficulty accessing my web server from the Internet.

I've port forwarded port 80 to my server of course, and I can access the web server from the WAN IP, but only if the source IP is in the same network as the server...

As you can see in the screenshot below I connected to my external IP on port 80 (covered in red) that gets forwarded to my server and the a 403 Forbidden error is displayed, which is the result I want for testing purposes.

[image]

However if I fire up a VPN connection and try to access the server from the same external IP as I tried before, I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`-error...

[image]

Could it be that the ISP has something to do with this? Or could this be an Apache configuration problem? Something else?

Comment: What does your ISP say about you hosting a server and have you asked them if they block inbound access to port 80?

Comment: The port it allowed and I have the option to setup a DMZ "in case you have a server running that needs to be accessible from the Internet", which I have enabled for the web server.